# Is this a design pattern? How to avoid a switch statement here

Tags: design-patterns

A picture is worth a thousand words hopefully

The bottom rectangle holds a bunch of child classes and a single base class. The top rectangle holds bits of logic

Each child class needs to run 1 or more bits of the top logic, there's no base class type commonality here

There are other 'top squares' of logic.

At present this is implemented using a switch statement (I know). The only alternative I can think of is a class with one method per piece of logic in and then each class can call the appropriate methods

The real life example is is for a bunch of reports and each report needs different gui elements on the page, but as I say there's no common behaviour that could be extracted into common base classes

[image]

A concrete example

Types of Reports

Annual

- Auditor
- Book
- Retail
- Census
- ...

Each report needs a combination of different elements

Annual & Auditor need

- From-> To dates
- Company Name
- Company type

Census & Trip need

- From-> To dates
- Council
- Religion
- Income

Retail needs

- Company Name
- Income

Book & Military & White need

- etc

Comment: The question is open to a lot of interpretations. While it's a pretty cool way of trying to describe your problem, you are better off giving a concrete example with some actual class names and code if you really want a helpful answer. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) can help you though the requirements are not that obvious. But I saw similar cases and use strategy for them.